# SignalR client hub event not firing after deploying on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I have developed a monitoring system using ASP.Net Webforms. I used SignalR 2.4.0 to trigger the auto-refresh function to have a live data monitoring. SignalR seems working on IIS Express but when I published it to the IIS 8.5, SignalR client hub events are not trigger.

Here's my Startup.cs

```
  public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
        var HubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration();
        app.MapSignalR();

    }
}
```

Here's my Hub:

```
[HubName("chartData")]
public class ChartDataHub : Hub , IRequiresSessionState
{

    SqlCommand objSQLCMD = new SqlCommand();
    DataSet dsResult = new DataSet();
    DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();
    DataTable dtResult2 = new DataTable();
    DataTable dtResult3 = new DataTable();
    string strSQL = "";


    private readonly static Lazy<ChartData> _instance = new Lazy<ChartData>(() => new ChartData());


    public static ChartData Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return _instance.Value;
        }
    }

    public readonly System.Timers.Timer _Timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    public ChartDataHub()
    {
        _Timer.Interval = 10000;
        _Timer.Elapsed += TimerCallBack;
        _Timer.Start();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Timer callback method
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="state"></param>
    private void TimerCallBack(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        GetClients().All.updateTakeInData(UpdateTRTakeInData());
        GetClients().All.updateTakeOutData(UpdateTRTakeOutData());
    }


    //GetTakeInData
    private object UpdateTRTakeInData()
    {
        List<GetTakeInCount> lst = new List<GetTakeInCount>();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(oDBMngr.ConnectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            strSQL = "SELECT Date,TotalPlan,TakeInQty,Order3Qty,DelayedQty FROM vewTRTakeInMonthly";
            objSQLCMD = new SqlCommand(strSQL, con);
            objSQLCMD.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            SqlDataReader rdr = objSQLCMD.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                GetTakeInCount rowData = new GetTakeInCount();
                rowData.TakeInQuantity = Convert.ToDouble(rdr["TakeInQty"].ToString());
                rowData.Date = rdr["Date"].ToString();
                rowData.PlanQuantity = rdr["TotalPlan"].ToString();
                rowData.AccPlanQty = Convert.ToDouble(rdr["TotalPlan"].ToString());
                rowData.OrderQty = Convert.ToDouble(rdr["Order3Qty"].ToString());
                rowData.DelayedQty = Convert.ToDouble(rdr["DelayedQty"].ToString());
                lst.Add(rowData);
            }
            return lst;
        }
    }

    //GetTakeOutData
    private object UpdateTRTakeOutData()
    {
        List<GetTakeOutCount> lst = new List<GetTakeOutCount>();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(oDBMngr.ConnectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            strSQL = "SELECT * FROM vewTRTakeOutMonthly";
            objSQLCMD = new SqlCommand(strSQL, con);
            objSQLCMD.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            SqlDataReader rdr = objSQLCMD.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                GetTakeOutCount rowData = new GetTakeOutCount();
                rowData.Date = rdr["Date"].ToString();
                rowData.TakeOutQty = Convert.ToDouble(rdr["TakeOutQty"].ToString());
                rowData.PlanQty = Convert.ToDouble(rdr["MonthlyPlan"].ToString());
                rowData.DI2Qty = Convert.ToDouble(rdr["DI2Quantity"].ToString());
                rowData.CPSStockQty = Convert.ToDouble(rdr["CPSStockQty"].ToString());
                lst.Add(rowData);
            }
            return lst;
        }
    }
    private static dynamic GetClients()
    {
        return GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChartDataHub>().Clients;
    }

}
public class GetTakeInCount
{
    public string Date { get; set; }

    public double TakeInQuantity { get; set; }

    public string PlanQuantity { get; set; }

    public double AccPlanQty { get; set; }

    public double OrderQty { get; set; }

    public double DelayedQty { get; set; }

}
public class GetTakeOutCount
{
    public string Date { get; set; }

    public double TakeOutQty { get; set; }

    public double CPSStockQty { get; set; }

    public double DI2Qty { get; set; }

    public double PlanQty { get; set; }

}
```

Here's my JS:

```
var chartData = $.connection.chartData;
chartData.client.updateTakeOutData = function (data) {
    //.........
}
$.connection.hub.logging = true;
$.connection.hub.start();
```

Here's the logs in IE:

```
[12:25:44 GMT+0800 (Taipei Standard Time)] SignalR: Client subscribed to hub 'chartdata'.
[12:25:44 GMT+0800 (Taipei Standard Time)] SignalR: Negotiating with '/DailyTakeInTakeOutMonitoring/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=2.0&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22chartdata%22%7D%5D'.
[12:25:44 GMT+0800 (Taipei Standard Time)] SignalR: Negotiating with '/DailyTakeInTakeOutMonitoring/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=2.0&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22chartdata%22%7D%5D'.
[12:25:47 GMT+0800 (Taipei Standard Time)] SignalR: serverSentEvents transport starting.
[12:25:47 GMT+0800 (Taipei Standard Time)] SignalR: This browser doesn't support SSE.
[12:25:47 GMT+0800 (Taipei Standard Time)] SignalR: serverSentEvents transport failed to connect. Attempting to fall back.
[12:25:47 GMT+0800 (Taipei Standard Time)] SignalR: foreverFrame transport starting.
[12:25:47 GMT+0800 (Taipei Standard Time)] SignalR: Binding to iframe's load event.
[12:25:48 GMT+0800 (Taipei Standard Time)] SignalR: Iframe transport started.
[12:25:48 GMT+0800 (Taipei Standard Time)] SignalR: foreverFrame transport connected. Initiating start request.
[12:25:52 GMT+0800 (Taipei Standard Time)] SignalR: The start request succeeded. Transitioning to the connected state.
[12:25:52 GMT+0800 (Taipei Standard Time)] SignalR: Now monitoring keep alive with a warning timeout of 13333.333333333332, keep alive timeout of 20000 and disconnecting timeout of 30000
[12:25:52 GMT+0800 (Taipei Standard Time)] SignalR: foreverFrame transport timed out when trying to connect.
```

It stops there and nothing client methods triggered.
I don't know whats wrong with my code. I need help guys.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: IIS7 doesn’t have websocket support and fallbacks don’t seem to be working. That’s a very old IIS to be using and will cause problems, at least with performance. Any possibility of updating to something from this decade?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I am using IIS Version 8.5. Will edit my post.

Comment: Then I assume websocket support isn’t turned on if it’s trying fallbacks. Can you check that it is?

Comment: I have checked and navigate to Web Server(IIS)  –>  Web Server –> Application Development Features. Application development feature is disabled(cannot **uncheck**). However the websocket protocol is installed.

Comment: I need your help Sir @SamiKuhmonen. Please help me to make this work :(

Comment: Any update sir @SamiKuhmonen?